# SED does not work in PHP under Windows

Tags: php, windows, sed, exec

I installed SED from GnuWin32 on my WinXp box running apache2.2 and PHP5

In a dos shell I run the command

```
c:\GnuWin32\bin\sed -i -r "s/[ ]{1,50}[,]/,/g" MASTER.txt
```

And everything works fine

But when trying to run in PHP as so:

```
exec("c:\\GnuWin32\\bin\\sed -i -r \"s/[ ]{1,50}[,]/,/g\" MASTER.txt");
```

Nothing happens.

I have tried searching for possible solutions, but cannot find any, but it is late here...so any help would be greatfully received please.

Cheers
Alexis

Comment: `exec("c:\\GnuWin32\\bin\\sed -i -r 's/[ ]{1,50}[,]/,/g' MASTER.txt");` maybe?

Comment: Can you print the return value? `exec("...command...", $output, $retval);`

Comment: $output is an array, but is empty and $retval has a value of 2...I can not find out what that meant though.
I also tried with single quotes instead of escaped double and still nothing.. In fact in the command line, single quotes do not work at all

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem...turns out I missed out the path of the file I wanted to replace data in. In the command line I was running the command within that directory....always the simple things that one overlooks!!
Thanks again for the responses.